# Pycharm - Django Console wrong path (Windows Host, Linux Guest)

Tags: django, console, pycharm

I've been trying out PyCharm for the Django Tutorial project lately and I ran into a problem with the Django Console (and manage.py tasks).
I'm running Windows 7 with PyCharm 2.7.2 and use a Ubuntu 12.04 Virtualbox (with virtualenv) for the project. I've mapped the my development folder as a samba drive on my windows host so I can access my project with PyCharm. I've set up a remote interpreter and I can start my project just fine without any errors. However if I try to use the "Run manage.py task" or "Run Django Console" menu points I receive the following output:

```
ssh://mz@192.168.56.101:22/home/mz/.virtualenvs/pollstutorial/bin/python -u /home/mz/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py runserver Z:/pollstutorial
bash: Zeile 0: cd: Z:/pollstutorial: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mz/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 24, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 170, in run_module
mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 103, in _get_module_details
raise ImportError("No module named %s" % mod_name)
ImportError: No module named manage

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As you can see it appends the Windows path to the project rather than the linux path in the first line. Now I know I can just add the path inside the django_manage.py file (sys.path.append('/path/to/project')) and it works just fine. But since this file is shared across all projects this is probably not the best idea.

So does anyone know if it's possible to edit the path thats passed to django_manage.py? I've tried a couple of things, but none had any effect.

**edit: Ok, solved it.**
CrazyCoder is exactly right. Don't use a network mapped sambadrive to develop, instead setup Deployment in the Project Settings. It's crucial that you select SFTP, because the if you don't you will still get the wrong path. After I did this it finally worked.

Comment: PyCharm 2.7.2 should work fine if you have Deployment configured correctly. Path mappings are taken from the deployment settings, so you need to have a local copy of the project on your Windows machine with the SFTP deployment to the Linux machine. When running, PyCharm will know how to map local windows folder to the remote Linux folder from the deployment configuration mappings. Dummy deployment configuration for the mapped drive may work as well but is not recommended for performance reasons.

Comment: Ok, so I don't really need to map the network drive on my windows machine then, got it. I've set up the Deployment thing and downloaded the project from my virtual box (deleted the .idea folder beforehand) and now I'm as far as I was before, meaning the Consoles path is still wrong.
There are settings for both the python and django console in the Project Settings but when I try to change the path mappings it doesn't save them...could this be my problem?

Comment: Double check your path mappings, SFTP root path should be set to the project root on the remote server, Deployment path on server should be just `/` (representing the project root). If it still doesn't work, [submit a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Deployment configuration with the SFTP server and properly configured path mappings. This way PyCharm will be able to map local Windows paths to the Remote Linux path and start the app with the remote interpreter and appropriate paths directly on the server.

Properly configured deployment is required for this configuration to work properly.